# Count not incrementing even though if statement is hit

Tags: c++, string

having some trouble with a count variable i have created for a bad word filter.  Everytime the bad word check is hit i want the count to increment.  Ive tried it numerous ways but the variable will still not increment.

I have tried it as

```
badCount = badCount + 1;
badCount + 1;
badCount = badCount++;
badCount ++;
```

But none of these ways work.  I no this is a simple soultion but after a while i debugging i am looking to seek some help.

This is my code below.

```
bool Player::AcceptableChat(const string& p_string) {
    //Old filter.
    //vector<string> vulger = { "fuck", "cunt", "dick", "fanny", "vagina", "bastard", "wanker", "penis", "shithead", "asshole", "bitch", "bollox",
    //"dike", "gay", "lesbian", "fucker", "wank", "masturbate", "tit", "boobs", "bent", "dickhead", "blowjob", "pussy","shit" };

    int badCount = 0;
    vector<string> vulgar;
    ifstream file("filter/Banned.txt");
    string word, temp;
    if (file.is_open()) {
        while (file.good()) {
            getline(file, word);
            vulgar.push_back(word);
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "Not loaded";
    }
    //Eliminates the user entering curse words for a name.
    for (vector<string>::iterator it = vulgar.begin(); it != vulgar.end(); it++) {
        if ((p_string == *it) || (p_string.find(*it) != std::string::npos)) {
            badCount++;                 
            //Testing what words are been neglected by the if statement.
            string ip = SocketLib::GetIPString(m_connection->GetRemoteAddress());
            USERLOG.Log("Player: " + m_name + "\tBanned Word: " + *it + "\tIp Address: " + ip);
            return false;
        }
    }
    cout << "Bad Count: " << badCount << endl;
    if (badCount == 3) {
        m_connection->Close();
    }
}
```

The function is then called above when sending a string to the connection.

```
if (AcceptableChat(p_string)) {
    Conn()->Protocol().SendString(*Conn(), p_string + newline);
}
else {
    Conn()->Protocol().SendString(*Conn(), "This message is offensive !!!" + newline);
}
```

Comment: I doubt incrementing a variable is the problem. Do you even pass the condition in the `if` ?

Comment: `return false` after `badCount++;` will completely exit the function which prevents any printing, is that intended?

Comment: Have you set a break point on your `badCount++;` and ran the code in a debugger to see if it ever gets hit?

Comment: yep of course.  I have been debugging it for ages anytime i enter a listed curse word the if statement is hit and so is the incremented variable

Comment: You'll want to provide a full `main()` that someone can run and the input that you are providing to this code...

Comment: I can't spot `badword` actually, could you improve your question and make it consistent please. Consider to setup a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that everyone can reproduce your problems.

Comment: @Namfuak well it is intentended for the purpose of giving me a negative value if a curse word is enetered for a seperate function.  Any suggestions?  putting the increment after the false return does nothing :S

Comment: As @Namfuak pointed out, you exit the function. The rest of the code/logic in the function is not executed at that point. You probably just want: `return badCount == 0` at the very end of your function. and remove the existing return call.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sorry it is a typo, it is badCount.

Comment: Unrelated to the problem, but consider using `for( string &str : vulgar )` if you have a C++11 compiler, it's so much cleaner.

Comment: p_string is the word the player would enter for the chat.  I dont think its related to the solution or understanding so i didnt post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you hit the incrementation, your counter will be incremented, thats a fact and it can't be changed. Now how did you find that it was not incremented ? I'm 100% sure that if you cout `badCount` before and after, you will see the increment. You should know that since you have a return (`badCount` goes out of scope) after the only assignment to `badCount`, the compiler will optimize it (maybe even with -O0, as it's trivial), so `badCount` probably don't even exist in the first place in your compiled program.

Maybe you wanted `badCount` to be a global variable ? Or static at least, if you keep it local, you won't ever see a difference after the call.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67174/discussion-on-answer-by-elderbug-count-not-incrementing-even-though-if-statement).

Answer (score 0):

You don't show enough context here, but anyway:

As long `badCount` isn't a class member or static variable, it's value will never go further than `1` because you're returning from your actual scope, when the condition is met

```
for (vector<string>::iterator it = vulgar.begin(); it != vulgar.end(); it++) {
    if ((p_string == *it) || (p_string.find(*it) != std::string::npos)) {
         //Testing what words are been neglected by the if statement.
         string ip = SocketLib::GetIPString(m_connection->GetRemoteAddress());
         USERLOG.Log("Player: " + m_name + "\tBanned Word: " + *it + "\tIp Address: " + ip);
         badCount++;
         return false; // This seems to be cause of your problems
     }

     // This code part is never reached for bad words
     cout << "Bad Count: " << badCount << endl;
     if (badCount == 3) {
         m_connection->Close();
     }
}
```

You probably want to have

```
for (vector<string>::iterator it = vulgar.begin(); it != vulgar.end(); it++) {
    if ((p_string == *it) || (p_string.find(*it) != std::string::npos)) {
         //Testing what words are been neglected by the if statement.
         string ip = SocketLib::GetIPString(m_connection->GetRemoteAddress());
         USERLOG.Log("Player: " + m_name + "\tBanned Word: " + *it + "\tIp Address: " + ip);
         badCount++;
         // moved return false; ...
     }

     cout << "Bad Count: " << badCount << endl;
     if (badCount == 3) {
         m_connection->Close();
         // ... here
         return false;
     }
}
```

Comment: I cant remove that without the purpose of the function breaking...

Comment: Since you didn't include all of the function code, it is hard to say where to place the return statement, but where it is now is not logically correct, the way you have approached the algorithm.

Comment: I will edit the post and add the function now.

Comment: @ConorPendlebury I've made a small change, where to move the return statement.

Comment: @Zéychin My crystal ball came back from the service station today. I don't know what they did, but it works better than ever now ;-) ...

Comment: I more meant that in the original post, the code ended abruptly without a closing brace. I didn't want any non-included implementation to get lost. :P. (and actually, between the OP and the edit, some braces have moved around... (The `if (badCount == 3)` check is no longer in the for loop, for example.)

Answer (score 0):

Move `int badCount = 0;` outside of your function.

Your code seems to want to track the number of "banned words" that a user uses, and once it hits 3, you want to kick them (drop connection). To do this, your code uses a local variable to store `badCount`. When your code discovers the first bad word, it increments this local variable, and then EXITS. So when you again scan the user's input, you are always at 1 for the first bad word found.

Moving `badCount` outside the function will have it retain its value between calls. Now, you can accumulate how many bad words a user has used.

You could open yourself up to a bug where the bad counts accumulate across multiple users, so I would suggest that you pass in the user's `badCount` by reference from your calling function. That would let the calling function control when to reset `badCount`, such as whenever you start processing a new user's input.

Comment: It will not close the connection until 3 bad words have been detected and then the user sends a message with no bad words, due to the placement of the return call.